# Python 3: RuntimeWarning with numpy.power

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, integer, pow

When using `numpy.power(2,N)`, where `N` is an integer, I encounter the following issue:

```
In[1] np.power(2,63)
Out[1] -9223372036854775808
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
```

and even more strangely,

```
In[2] np.power(2,63)*2
Out[2] 0
```

This happens for all exponents greater than or equal to 63. I thought that large integer are not an issue in Python - what's wrong here, then?

Comment: You aren't dealing with Python integers here, you are dealing with NumPy integers which are of a fixed size (64 bits in this case), which is a prerequisite for the fast vectorized math operations that NumPy provides.  If you want to use Python ints, write `2**63` or `pow(2, 63)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large integers are not a problem with Python because Python only has one integer type and that is of arbitrary precision. But [NumPy uses normal "C" data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) and these have limited precision:

```
>>> 2 ** 63              # Python
9223372036854775808

>>> np.int64(2) ** 63    # NumPy
-9223372036854775808
```

On most systems 64bit is the highest precision integer type available with plain NumPy. So if you're dealing with larger numbers you could use `float` dtypes or simply use Python integers with normal lists or NumPy object arrays (not really recommended).